# How to declare a property of NSArray of NSObjects in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom User class where I am storing user data. For now I have Group class where I want to add Users as an array. Somewhere I seen once something like, but I lost it and can't find.

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) User<NSArray> *groupUsers;
```

Do you know how to make it right syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<User*> *groupUsers;`

Comment: Ask google for **objective-c generics** ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do correction in your code.The correct syntax should be:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray<User*> *groupUsers;
```

Comment: thanks! it's exactly I need!